# How to jump to the middle of a timeline/tween and continue it from that point

Tags: javascript, jquery, tween, scrollmagic, gsap

I need to be able to jump to the middle of a tween that is lower down on the page and hasn't begun, and then begin the tween at the point where I jumped in.

When I click on the nav menu (seen as an unloaded image in the header), I need to be taken to the correct sliding panel, then have the scrolling continue from there. For example, if I click on "Degrees" in the menu, I want to be taken to the "Degrees" panel, then be able to scroll on to the next panel, "People".

The problem is when I get to the panel, the scrolling jumps back to the beginning, the first panel "About", instead of continuing on seamlessly. How do I fix this?

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a24jvuu/5/#&togetherjs=oNEv1DEGe4) to view full code (in "Employment" menu button event listener, you can see my attempts with `play()` and `seek()` and `controller.ScrollTo()`, perhaps using them in an incorrect combination).

```
// Initialize ScrollMagic controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// Define movement of panels
    var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-11.11%"})    // to Degrees
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-22.22%"})    // to People
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-33.33%"})    // to Research
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-44.44%"})    // to Employment
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-55.56%"})    // to Employment2
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-66.67%"})    // to Employment3
        .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-77.78%"});   // to Resources

    // Create scene to pin and link animation
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
            triggerHook: "onLeave",
            duration: "600%"  // slows down scrolling
        })
        .setPin("#pinContainer")
        .setTween(wipeAnimation)
        //.addIndicators() 
        .addTo(controller);

    /**************************** MENU ****************************/

    $('.menu-btn').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var name = $(this).text();
            if (name == "Degrees") {
                wipeAnimation.seek(1);
                wipeAnimation.play(1);
            } else if (name == "People") {
                wipeAnimation.seek(2);
            } else if (name == "Research") {
                wipeAnimation.seek(3);
            } else if (name == "Employment") {
                //wipeAnimation.seek(4);
                //controller.scrollTo('#start');
             //   controller.scrollTo('#employmentAnchor')
            //scene.progress(0.56);

                //wipeAnimation.play(4);

                //alert(scene.progress());
                //scene.progress(0.5);
                //controller.scrollTo('#start');

                //alert('current pos: ' + controller.scrollPosMethod());
                //wipeAnimation.play(4);
                //wipeAnimation.start();
                //wipeAnimation.play(4);
            } else if (name == "Resources") {
                wipeAnimation.seek(5);
            }
        });
    })

    $('.menu').on('click', function() {
        $('nav').show();
    })
```

Comment: did you achieve this ever?